# SSLContext loadTrustMaterial(just the truststore)

Tags: java, ssl

*What I am trying to achieve:*

Able to write `SSLContextBuilder.create().loadTrustMaterial(getTrustStore()).build();`
with only the trust store.

*What did I try:*

```
public final SSLContext getSslContext() {
        try {
            return SSLContextBuilder.create().loadTrustMaterial(getTrustStore(),TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).build();
        } ...
        }
    }

    public KeyStore getTrustStore() throws Exception {
        final var trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        try (InputStream trustStoreFile = new FileInputStream("/path/to/truststore")) {
            final var trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            trustStore.load(trustStoreFile, "".toCharArray());
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            return trustStore;
        }
    }
```

*Issue:*

With several static analysis tools, I am always getting

```
in getSslContext. The loadTrustMaterial parameter, effectively disables verification of the SSL certificate trust chain.

Similarity ID: -196258711
```

*Question:*

How to fix this issue?

There is no API for public SSLContextBuilder loadKeyMaterial(KeyStore keystore). How can I just do the following in order to avoid the trust all strategy?

```
public final SSLContext getSslContext() {
        try {
            return SSLContextBuilder.create().loadTrustMaterial(getTrustStore()).build();
        } ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no issue to fix. The warning messages is correct. The `TrustAllStrategy` is radically insecure. Solution: don't use it.

Comment: BTW this is not 'just the truststore'. You are also loading a trust policy. And that's where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe the I should reformulate. Thank you for the comment. The point is that I do not want to use TrustAllStrategy, but the only API which exists requires a TrustStrategy, how to fix that?